# Extract field from POST

Tags: php

I converted an old cgi mailform form to PHP by simply doing the below and emailing $msg as the body of the email.
I'd like to extract the value of the field  "email" as a seperate variable to use as the reply-to address.

```
foreach ($_POST as $field=>$value) {
    if ($field != "submit") $msg .= $field . ": " . $value . "\n";
}
```

will something like $field[email] have the value of the email field in it?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` and show the output of it

Comment: Can you post some of your array? Hard to answer this without more information about the array. If the array contains `email => jointtech@example.com`, then yes you're on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it if you're working with a single dimension array. If you have an associative array, then you'll need to add another search variable.  An associative could look something like:

```
Array (1) (
  Array (3) (
   ["email"] =>
    [0] => jointtech@example.com
    [1] => bob@example.com
    [2] => tom@example.com
  )
)

foreach ($_POST as $field=>$value) {
  if ( strpos($field, 'submit') === false ) {
    $msg .= $field['email'] . ": " . $value . "\n";
}
```

If you have the associative array above, then the `$field['email']` will not work.